# Three.js will not run locally- any ideas?

Tags: github, three.js, webgl, local

So, I am trying my hand at Three.js now and am having some issues with running it-

Using the tutorial from the website-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(cube);

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
            alert("hit");
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because I used the script source from github, it works.
But, when I download the three.min.js or three.js file and run it locally like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(cube);

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
            alert("hit");
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It won't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you are running any web page from the local file system, expect problems.  In windows, the easiest way to run something locally is to download WebMatrix and that'll install you a copy of IIS express and there isn't much you have to do but a bit of clicking.